# Any chance knowing Facebook APP user ID ahead?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to create an internal profile page in my app for users before they actually sign-in via Facebook. Any chance knowing what would be each FB user APP USER ID ahead?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course that is not possible. Then why would you need sign-in

Comment: @WizKid - I don't see why not being able to get it ahead. Sign-in itself is used for the user to grant the app relevant permissions and generate the access token for it.

Comment: And for the user to tell you that they want to tell you who they are.

Comment: _“I don't see why not being able to get it ahead”_ - and I don’t see why you would have to create a profile page before they actually sign up.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the reply. It is a business wise issue, some of my users are very important & busy people and I rather prepare their profile myself before they actually log-in, as I definitely don't want them to sign-in to an empty one.

Comment: You mean you fill this profile with content manually, upfront? For certain, known users? Then it might make more sense to base that on something you can know beforehand, such as the email address.

Comment: @CBroe - OK the problem with it is that I don't know the users' FB email beforehand and in no way want to ask for it :) What could have help here is having a tool taking a FB user general ID and converting it to my FB App user ID, even though he/she didn't sign-in yet to my app...

Comment: There is no way of converting the global user id into an app-scoped one. What you want is not possible.